# How to schedule Jenkins job to run every last day of every month

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkins job to run monthly some DB tests. After reading about Jenkins format, I try to schedule build for every last day of every month like this:

```
TZ=Europe/Sofia
```

{
    H 06 31 1 *
H 06 28 2 *
H 06 31 3 *
H 06 30 4 *
H 06 31 5 *
H 06 30 6 *
H 06 31 7 *
H 06 31 8 *
H 06 30 9 *
H 19 31 10 *
H 06 30 11 *
H 06 31 12 *
    }

Is there smarter war for this runs ? And do you know why yesterday the job ran at 31-Oct-2018 18:54:00, not at 19:00 pm ?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you can achieve this easily without using some additional code to check if the next day is the first from the next month. 
This is the starting point: 0 23 28-31 * *

Comment: Thank you, sir. It worked when I replace "H" with minutes for building. For example: 30 06 28 2 * - will trigger job for 28-th of February